# Exception in SagePay Direct Integration Kit - c#\mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, opayo

We have upgraded our online shop from classic asp to asp.net\c#\mvc

Although our system works fine against the sagepay sandbox, we are getting an internal exception within the sagepay compiled dll when calling their ProcessDirectPaymentRequest method.

SagePay seem unable to help us, has anybody else had a similar issue and if so any tips on how you worked around it?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Hi David,

We've only just got back into this.

Exception is a generic error, object is null.

We have the source code for the DLL now and are working on a fix.

Looks like their internal classes don't contain all the parameters returned from the gateway.

I'll update this thread when we've fixed it.